# convert hexcode to html entity after parsing an xml document

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xml-serialization, xmlserializer, saxparser

While parsing one of the xml files using XML Serializer in java, the html entites are converting into its corresponding hexcode values(like for mdash output is "hexcode value-#x2014;") and hence reflecting into the final output file.
How to convert back the hexcode values back to html entities.

Comment: I'm not sure that "XML Serializer" tells us exactly what software you are using and how you are using it. There are lots of XML serializers in Java. Please tell us more precisely what you are doing. Also, have you set options to serialize as HTML?